# Capacitor based pulse generator

Tags: led, capacitor, clock, pulse

I want to make a simple circuit where LEDs are alternatively turned on. I have, say, 20 green LEDs and 20 red LEDs. The first half second, the red LEDs should be turned on, the next half second the green LEDs should be turned on, and so on. I'm doing this as a fun Christmas project and to force myself to learn more about electronics.

I found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5eoOV1IxkIU&ab_channel=EasyEDA) video, explaining simulation in EasyEDA, accidentally using a circuit that basically does what I want. I could blindly copy this circuit and add more LEDs. But to be able to learn something I want to understand what exactly happens in this circuit:

[image]

I have tried endlessly to understand this circuit but I always get stuck on my own logic:

1. When Q1 turns on, the + side of C1 is pulled to ground, resulting in -5V at the - side of C1. This cancels out the 5V coming through R2 and the resulting voltage at the junction to the right of C1 must be 0V.
2. Q2 will now turn on and the junction to the left of C2 will go to 0V. This results in Q1 turning on, but this is what we started with.
3. According to my logic above, Q1 and Q2 will both be turned on until C1 and C2 are drained and then stay turned off forever.

However, in the simulation in the video you clearly see the LEDs being turned on alternatingly. What am I missing?

When I search online, all explanations say that Q1 starts conducting when a negative voltage is applied to its base. I don't get this. Q1 is an NPN transistor. NPN transistors conduct when a voltage < 0.7 is applied to their base. I even simulated this in LTSpice:

[image]

Where the blue line is the input voltage V1 applied at the base of Q1 and the green line is the voltage at the collector of Q1.

Comment: See this post for explaining "half" of this circuit which is a "monostable" function. Astable is thus "two" cascaded chained monostables but closed loop .  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/509314/astable-multivibrator-circuit-analysis/589355#589355  Note that this astable can't function if it has EXACTLY symmetrical components values. But things are well done, no transistor are exactly identical ... One is faster than the other ...

Comment: But this circuit uses an oscillator as input, which is exactly the part I am trying to build and understand.

Comment: Yes, the monostable use a "pulse" as input ... which is built by the second monostable in a closed loop.

Comment: https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/astable-multivibrator-how-does-it-work.32164/#post-200183

Comment: or this one https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/591786/explanation-of-blinking-circuit-with-transistors/591802#591802

Comment: You missed the point about transistor conduction. Positive voltage applied to the base opens the transistor. The green line clearly shows there is voltage on collector during positive sine (the inverse function of transistor , i.e. base=high ---> collector=low).

Comment: Ohh, that's right. Now I figured out what went wrong inside my brain. When the voltage at the collector is high, this corresponds to the LED being turned off instead of on. I interpreted it exactly the other way around. Thank you so much for being so patient with me xD

Comment: Should I delete this question since it's rubbish for being based on a wrong assumption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider Q1 is closed and C1 is charged to 4.3V through path +5v,R1,Led1,C1,Q2_Vbe,Gnd.

Now, the Q1 is suddenly open due to some reason.

What happen is the +pole of C1 is grounded and the -pole is at potential -4.3v below Gnd (also as the base of Q2).

This leads the Q2 is immediately off with it's collector at +5V so C2 starts to charge through path +5v,R4,Led2,C2,Q1_Vbe,Gnd. This charging current (with R3 current) holds the Q1 open.

Very important, during this period the C1 which was initially charged to 4.3V is recharged to -0.7V (you see right, the negative voltage on electrolytic cap). This recharging is very slow end up with opening Q2 (0.7v on base of Q2, C1 +pole still on Gnd) as well as was Q1 in second sentence of this answer.

This process now runs from opposite side.

Comment: Ok, but in your 4th paragraph you say that C2 starts to charge throug a path that goes through Q1_Vbe. This is the part that I don't get. A positive current on the base of an NPN transistor means the transistor is open and not closed. If a current flows from the base of Q1 to GND, this must mean Q1 is open, meaning LED1 could not be on and the + of C1 would no longer be grounded.

Comment: If the current flows to Q1 base, the Q1 is open (Q1 collector is at Gnd / 0V), the Led1 is ON, the +pole of C1 is grounded.

Comment: "If the current flows to Q1 base, the Q1 is open" I agree with you so far. "Q1 collector is at Gnd / 0V", this I don't understand. If Q1 is open, it is not conducting and so the collector cannot be connected to ground since the collector and emitter of Q1 are not connected to each other.

Comment: "Q1 open" means the transistor is in saturation, so almost no drop on Vce. The full current flows through collector (Led1).

Comment: Please don't use "open" to indicate that a transistor is saturated/conducting - it is confusing because an open switch or open circuit is not conducting.